# What is the point of a system user?

Tags: users, group, useradd

Ok so when you look at the system user the point of the system user is to run services with minimal permissions, and to have a user that doesn't have a password or ssh. The issue I have with this is that to actually do anything you need to give that user a shell to run the service, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of not giving it a shell to begin with. I am wondering if I am using this wrong and if so what is the correct way to get a service running off of a system user. I used this command to create the user `adduser --system --disabled-login --disabled-password --home /usr/local/appname appname`
and I used this command to actually use the user/issue commands `sudo su -s /bin/bash appname -C <command>`

Answer (score 0):

> to actually do anything you need to give that user a shell to run the service

```
sudo -u appname <command>
```

You are doing things very wrong. Most systems should have a service manager to deal with starting your services for you (`sudo service apache2 start`). And many services already include tools for starting them manually with the correct user (`sudo apachectl start`).

Fundamentally, whether a user has a login shell, a password, a home directory, or ssh access are all independent. Users for people on a shared system probably have all of them, but any combination is valid.

The most secure combination is none of them. This prevents people from logging in to the machine as that user. The only way to run anything as that user is then to already have root access.